# Is it possible to decrease *provisioned* size of CentOS 6.5 VMDK (on ESXi 6.0) or no?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Although there are plenty of articles on how to shrink the *used* size of a VMDK, I can't find anything about **actually shrinking the *provisioned* size of a VMDK.** I have seen write-ups where people state that whatever you start with, you are permanently stuck with, but that was back on ESXi 5.0.

I have tried to "punch holes" in the VMDK with vmkfstools via SSH, but it didn't seem to work. Is this possible or no? I do have vCSA 6 with vMotion, plus a copy of VMware Convertor. The particular VM I am working with this time is CentOS 6.5 (not yet in production, so I can take risks). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although unsupported (just make sure you have a good backup first), this is what worked for me with this (originally thick-provisioned, eager zeroed) CentOS VMDK:

- Change VMDK from thick to thin-provisioned. I used Storage vMotion, but VMware Converter would also work.
- Shutdown VM and SSH into ESXi host where it lives.
- ["Punchzero" in the VMDK via VMKFSTools](http://buildvirtual.net/reclaim-used-space-with-vmkfstools-punchzero/).
- Boot VM to GParted and shrink VMDK to smallest possible size (was 40 GB in my case).
- Create slightly larger (went with 50 GB) secondary VMDK for the VM. Ensure it is stored in the same datastore as original VMDK and has different name.
- Boot VM to cloneZilla and clone disk-to-disk via **"expert mode" with option: -icds**
- BE SURE TO KEEP A COPY OF THE ORIGINAL VMX FILE in case something breaks! Download and edit VMX file (I use Notepad++). Update VMDX name from old (larger) to new (smaller) one, then reupload VMX file to VM's folder (thus replacing it). Alternatively, you can SSH into the host and make the edits via VI if you are comfortable doing so. Be sure to `cp orig.vmx backup.vmx` first if you go this route.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that you can do this by editing the VMDK desriptor file, but I've never done this and I suspect it isn't a supported operation.

A supported method for doing this would be to perform a conversion of the VM with the VMware Converter and editing the destination disk size during the conversion wizard.

Comment: +1, as the vconverter method is the only one I know of (or you backup, dettach, recreate the volume (smaller), restore and destroy the old volume if it's not the boot volume)

Comment: VMware converter isn't giving me the option to change the size during conversion. Any ideas why this is? "Data copy type: Copy all disks and maintain layout" is my only option.

Comment: @KidACrimson Your target (esx, vmworkstation, etc..) is what ?

Comment: Yes, you definitely want to sue the VMware converter for this. It's entirely possible to do this manually almost as you describe, but one must first shrink ALL OF the affected guest disk structures beforehand if they intend to shrink the backing file. Depending on the configuration of the guest, this ranges from tedious to impossible.

Comment: Thanks, @yagmoth555. My target is the same ESXi server. We have 3, so I can use another one if need be, so this one is the "lab" server (pre-production use).

Comment: Still trying VMware Converter with no luck. It doesn't seem to matter which host or datastore I choose: I cannot change the size of VirtualDisk1. I can change thick/thin provisioned, but that's it. 

I have a recent Veeam backup of this VM, so I will try editing the VMDK descriptor file...

Comment: According to this VMware forum post, what I'm seeing is by design (last post): https://communities.vmware.com/thread/482607?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Ah. My bad. I didn't realize that you couldn't do this with non-Windows virtual machines.

Comment: No worries. I'm trying to nano the .VMDK file, but don't see a place to change the size of the virtual disk. Any ideas?

Comment: @KidACrimson You need to do like I told then, the hard way. Remove the hdd (vmdk indirectly) from the vm, create a smaller's one and restore the files onto it.

Comment: I have created a new (secondary, smaller) VMDK. However, I obviously cannot boot into the CentOS v6.5 VM to copy it's own root-level data since that would be actively using the VMDK. What would be best for this, CloneZilla?

Comment: I booted to GParted to find the minimum size for the original VMDK, shrunk it and am cloning old VMDK to new via CloneZilla (with **advanced mode -icds option**). Once this is done I can backup and edit the VMDX file to point to the new VMDK and fingers crossed, it works...

Comment: Shrinking with GParted, then cloning larger to smaller VMDK with CloneZilla  (with "expert mode" -icds option) worked! I just had to edit the VMX file to point to the new, smaller VMDX and the VM booted right up!